# Cannot compare present and form date in javascript (angular form)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, date, datetime

In html,the input date tag is given like this:

```
<input type="date" placeholder="Select You Date of Birth" ng-model="dob">
```

In controller I have written the code like this:

```
$scope.dateOfBirth = new Date(dob).valueOf();
$scope.presentDate = new Date().valueOf();
if($scope.presentDate <= $scope.dateOfBirth){
    $ionicPopup.alert({
       content: 'Date of birth should be before current date'
    })
}
```

I have the set the condition that the date of birth(dob) should be less then present date other wise the ionic warning popup will appear.But when i give the current date as dob, the ionic warning popup is not showing.Though when the dob is greater than the present date,the ionic popup is working correctly.

I have added a fiddle for testing.
Thanks for your time.

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/25286/

Comment: use `<= ` instead of `<`

Comment: @Anita did it but didnt get corrected.Am gonna edit it in the question.Thanks

Comment: 1)Your date format "input" can not correspond  to the format of Date() function. 2) Erase  valueOf().

Comment: @nick_n_a Thanks for your time.Tried your way but still if the present date is equal to date of birth,the error popup is shown

Comment: if you use @nick_n_a  way , you must set midnight presentDate  because $scope.presentDate has current date time.  like this ->> $scope.presentDate.setHours(0,0,0,0); $scope.dateOfBirth.setHours(0,0,0,0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use format date yyyymmdd

instead of new Date().valueOf();

like this :

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.dobSubmit = function(dob){
    $scope.dateOfBirth = new Date(dob);
    $scope.presentDate = new Date();
    if(formatDateYmd($scope.presentDate) > formatDateYmd($scope.dateOfBirth)){
      alert('present date is greater than date of birth which is correct format');
    }
    else{
      alert('date of birth is greater or equal to present date which is incorrect format');
    }
  }


  var formatDateYmd = function(date) {
    var day = date.getDate();
    var monthIndex = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    console.log(''+year+ (monthIndex < 10 ? '0' + monthIndex : monthIndex) + (day < 10 ? '0' + day : day));
    return ''+year+ (monthIndex < 10 ? '0' + monthIndex : monthIndex) + (day < 10 ? '0' + day : day);

  }

}
```

Comment: Can use the getDay getMonth and getFullYear but that will be a long comparison.Wanted to code this way to shorten the comparison.Will do your way if didnt get any solution.

Comment: Thanks for your time.감사하다.Will upvote and select your answer as working correctly

Comment: Sorry my bad.It was only working partially.But still gonna upvote your answer as it gave me hints to the full answer.Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I edited my code and it is working.Thanks to 이동권 for his hints.

```
    //getting milliseconds passed before dob date
    $scope.dateOfBirth = new Date(dob).valueOf();

    //getting day,month and year of dob
    $scope.dobDay = new Date(dob).getDate();
    $scope.dobMonth = new Date(dob).getMonth();
    $scope.dobYear = new Date(dob).getFullYear();

    //getting milliseconds passed before present date
    $scope.presentDate = new Date().valueOf();

    //getting day,month and year of present date
    $scope.presentDay = new Date().getDate();
    $scope.presentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
    $scope.presentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

    if(dob == undefined){
        $ionicPopup.alert({
           content: 'Please enter your date of birth'
        })
    }
    else if($scope.dateOfBirth > $scope.presentDate){
        $ionicPopup.alert({
           content: 'Date of birth should be before current date'
        })
    }
    else if(($scope.dobDay == $scope.presentDay)&&($scope.dobMonth == $scope.presentMonth)&&($scope.dobYear == $scope.presentYear)){
        $ionicPopup.alert({
           content: 'Date of birth can\'t be same as current date'
        })
    }
    else{
        $state.dob = dob;
        $state.go('sign_gender');
    }
```